# Update/Delete a sub document in mongodb using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Vote
{
    public string VoteId { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<VoteAnswer> AnswerList { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class VoteOption
{
    public string OptionId { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public double VoteCount { get; set; }
}
```

How can i update/delete a `VoteOption` in a `Vote` where `VoteId = voteId` and `OptionId = optionId`? Using `C#` driver.

First I get VoteOption by:

```
        var v = col.FindOneAs<Vote>(Query.EQ("VoteID", voteId));
        VoteOption vo = v.AnswerList.Find(x => x.OptionId == optionId);
```

End set some value to it:

```
vo.OptionName = "some option chose";
vo.VoteCount = 1000;
```

But i don't know what next step to update this `vo` to `Vote parent`.

And, if i want to delete this `vo`, show me that way!

Data in MongoDB like that:

```
{
  "_id" : "460b3a7ff100",
  "Question" : "this is question?",
  "AnswerList" : [{
      "OptionId" : "1",
      "OptionName" : "Option 1",
      "VoteCount" : 0.0
    }, {
      "OptionId" : "2",
      "OptionName" : "Option 2",
      "VoteCount" : 0.0
    }, {
      "OptionId" : "3",
      "OptionName" : "Option 3",
      "VoteCount" : 0.0
    }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the $ operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To update subdocument you can use this:

```
var update = Update.Set("AnswerList.$.OptionName", "new").Set("AnswerList.$.VoteCount", 5);
collection.Update(Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new BsonObjectId("50f3c313f216ff18c01d1eb0")), Query.EQ("AnswerList.OptionId", "1")), update);
```

profiler:

```
"query" : { "_id" : ObjectId("50f3c313f216ff18c01d1eb0"), "AnswerList.OptionId" : "1" },
"updateobj" : { "$set" : { "AnswerList.$.OptionName" : "new", "AnswerList.$.VoteCount" : 5 } }
```

And to remove:

```
var pull = Update<Vote>.Pull(x => x.AnswerList, builder => builder.EQ(q => q.OptionId, "2"));
collection.Update(Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new BsonObjectId("50f3c313f216ff18c01d1eb0")), Query.EQ("AnswerList.OptionId", "2")), pull);
```

profiler:

```
"query" : { "_id" : ObjectId("50f3c313f216ff18c01d1eb0"), "AnswerList.OptionId" : "2" },
"updateobj" : { "$pull" : { "AnswerList" : { "OptionId" : "2" } } }
```

Another way is to update parent document with modified child collection.

Comment: Updating the parent directly is a bad advise. What if "user1" is changing the subdocument ```optionId: 1``` while another user is changing subdocument ```optionId: 2``` at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Example function for update like count add like user  using c#    
public PostModel LikeComment(LikeModel like)
{
    PostModel post = new PostModel();

    _client = new MongoClient();
    _database = _client.GetDatabase("post");
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<PostModel>("post");

    var _filter = Builders<PostModel>.Filter.And(
    Builders<PostModel>.Filter.Where(x => x.PostId == like.PostId),
    Builders<PostModel>.Filter.Eq("Comments.CommentId", like.CommentId));

    var _currentLike = collection.Find(Builders<PostModel>.Filter.Eq("PostId", like.PostId)).FirstOrDefault().Comments.Find(f => f.CommentId == like.CommentId).Like;

    var update = Builders<PostModel>.Update.Set("Comments.$.Like", _currentLike + 1);
    collection.FindOneAndUpdate(_filter, update);

    var addUser = Builders<PostModel>.Update.Push("Comments.$.LikeUsers", like.UserId);
    collection.FindOneAndUpdate(_filter, addUser);

    var _findResult = collection.Find(_filter).FirstOrDefault();

    return _findResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Delete comment
public PostModel delcomment(int postId, int commentId)
{
    _client = new MongoClient();
    _database = _client.GetDatabase("post");
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<PostModel>("post");

    var filter = Builders<PostModel>.Filter.Eq("PostId", postId);

    var update = Builders<PostModel>.Update.PullFilter("Comments",
    Builders<Comments>.Filter.Eq("CommentId", commentId));

    collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update);

    var _findResult = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
    return _findResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Late answer** but this is how you do it without having strings. If you modify your properties code will not compile. First time using expression tries in production code! They are awesome!

Models:

```
class Phone
{
  public string _id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

            // Contain multiple lines as subdocument
  public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}

class Line
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**  this is how I create my update statements without depending on strings.

```
var update = new UpdateDocument<Phone>();

// set filter
update.SetFilter(x => x._id == "123456789");

update.AddValueToUpdate(p => p.Name, "New Name");
update.AddValueToUpdate(p => p.Lines[0].Name, "Line 1");
update.AddValueToUpdate(p => p.Lines[1].Name, "Line 2");
update.AddValueToUpdate(p => p.DateCreated, DateTime.UtcNow);


var updateQuery = update.Build();
```

This creates this!  That is what you need to pass to mondo in order to do the update

```
{ "_id" : "123456789" },
{$set:
  {"Name":"New Name","Lines.0.Name":"Line 1","Lines.1.Name":"Line 2","DateCreated":ISODate("2021-04-30T16:04:59.332Z")}
}
```

If you wish that code to work here are the helper classes:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;

class UpdateDocument<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     _id of document to update. 
    /// </summary>
    private string _filter;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Example:
    ///     FirstName, Antonio
    ///     Education.Elementary.Year, 2004
    /// </summary>
    private List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> _valuesToUpdate { get; set; } = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    public void SetFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterDefinition)
    {
        var documentSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<T>();
        var where = Builders<T>.Filter.Where(filterDefinition).Render(documentSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);
        _filter = where.ToJson();
    }

    public void AddValueToUpdate(string name, object value)
    {
        _valuesToUpdate.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name, value));
    }

    public void AddValueToUpdate(Expression<Func<T, object>> name, object value)
    {
        var memberExpression = name.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            var unaryExpression = name.Body as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExpression != null && unaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
                memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }

        var result = memberExpression.ToString();
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf('.') + 1);

        if (result.Contains("get_Item"))
            result = Regex.Replace(result, @"(?x) get_Item \( (\d+) \)", m => $"{m.Groups[1].Value}");

        AddValueToUpdate(result, value);
    }

    public string Build()
    {
        if (_valuesToUpdate.Any() == false)
        {
            // nothing to update
            return null;
        }

        /*
update({ 
_id: 7, 
"comments._id": ObjectId("4da4e7d1590295d4eb81c0c7")
},{
$set: {"comments.$.type": abc}
}, false, true
);
            */

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(_filter);
        sb.Append(',');

        sb.Append("{");
        {
            sb.Append("$set:{");
            foreach (var item in _valuesToUpdate)
            {
                sb.Append('"');
                sb.Append(item.Key);
                sb.Append('"');
                sb.Append(':');

                var value = BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson(item.Value);
                sb.Append(value);
                sb.Append(',');
            }
            // remove last comma
            sb.Length--;
            sb.Append('}');
        }
        sb.Append("}");

        return sb.ToString();




    }


}
```