# Is there a strongly-typed way to update a subdocument in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the need to update a subdocument in Mongo, and this is how I did it. This screenshot shows what my documents look like. And the code below it shows how I updated Geddy’s name and instrument.

[image]

Note: This approach was taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14315531/279516):

```
var update = Update.Set("Members.$.Instrument", "Keyboards").Set("Members.$.LastName", "Leex");

var collection = MongoDbHelper.Db.GetCollection<Band>("Bands");
collection.Update(Query.And(Query.EQ("Name", "Rush"), Query.EQ("Members.FirstName", "Geddy")), update);
```

**Is there another/better way to do this that makes use of strongly-typed properties instead of all of these string literals?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for writing queries or updates like this one (i.e. querying against individual subfields of arrays and using "$" in the update) using the typed builders.

The difficulty is coming up with expressions that compile without errors and yet express the desired intent correctly.

For example, the following might be a workable design, but using -1 as an index value is kind of hacky:

```
var query = Query.And(
    Query<Band>.EQ(b => b.Name == "Rush"),
    Query<Band>.EQ(b => b.Members[-1].FirstName == "Geddy"));
var update = Update<Band>
    .Set(b => b.Members[-1].Instrument, "Keyboards")
    .Set(b => b.Members[-1].LastName, "Leex");
```

Note: this is just a possible design for supporting "$" in typed builders. It is not actually implemented this way.

If you have any ideas for how a type safe version of this could be expressed you should create a JIRA ticket suggesting the feature.

Comment: What does -1 mean? Is that the same thing as $?

Comment: I tried this and got two compilation errors: `No overload for method 'EQ' takes 1 arguments` and `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApp1.Documents.Musician>'`

Comment: -1 is just an example of one *possible* way to express queries and updates involving "$". It is not actually implemented.

Comment: Okay, I took your example and tried many different ways to make it work, and it doesn't. So the bottom line is what you suggested can't be done, but what you wrote would be a nice way for it to work, *if* that way existed.

Comment: Since `ElementAt` is baked in to the C# driver, it's too bad there isn't an extension method on a `List<T>` which would allow the expression: `b => b.Members.FirstPosition().FirstName` for example. It's actually a very simple addition given how `ElementAt` works. (I'd rather there be a descriptive method than a magic number of some sort).