# How to update document's array field's specific indexed value using Mongodb c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

suppose i have data like this

```
{
 _id: '14577543',
 items: [
      { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
      { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
      { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
      { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
   ]
}
```

How can i update let say 2nd item of document's array field `(items)` in `Mongodb C#` driver ? i don't want the way of doing this in `Mongo Javascript` wrapper. I just want to know the right syntax. How can i do that?

Comment: Have a look at [Update/Delete a sub document in mongodb using C# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313649/update-delete-a-sub-document-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver). it might help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update an element of an array object, you'll have to retrieve the array object (items) first, update it and then save it back. Following should get you to do what you need.

```
// This is not a correct formatted objectID but to show you how it 'would' work
var filter = Builders<ClassObject>.Filter.Eq(x => x._id, ObjectId("14577543")); 
var data = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
var element = data.items.ElementAt(1); // 0 indexed.
element.y = 2;
element.x = 5;

collection.FindOneAndUpdate<ClassObject>(
    x => x._id == ObjectId("15477543"), 
    Builders<ClassObject>.Update.Set(ri => ri.items, data.items),
    new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<ClassObject, ClassObject>() { IsUpsert = true }
);
```