# Whole MongoDB documented deleted when filtering on a subdocument - c# delete

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I've created my MongoDB documents below with subdocuments/arrays, however the arrays aren't named and I would like to delete the whole subdocument if a match is found on an elements within a subdocument.

For example, if a match is found on userID and userLogs.Name. My query is deleting the whole documents instead of only the userLog array. I've also tried other methods such as Pull and PullFilter whilst researching this topic but it doesn't seem to work with this structure, please can you advise on whether there is a way or if I will have to change my document structure?

Document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("43535"),
    "userID" : "1",
    "userLogs" : [
        {
            "logID" : 1,
            "Name" : "Book 1",
            "Genre" : "Fiction",
             ....
         },
        {
            "logID" : 2,
            "Name" : "Book 2",
            "Genre" : "Non-Fiction",
             ....
         }
     ]
}
```

C# Code behind

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");

var arrayFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userID", uID) &
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userLogs.Name", name);

collection.DeleteOne(arrayFilter);
```

Comment: `DeleteOne()` always delete the document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/ - You want to update the document. See `$` operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/ This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313649/update-delete-a-sub-document-in-mongodb-using-c-sharp-driver - This should be a good starting point in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christoph! I also solved this using the following method:

```
var query = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("UserID", uID) &
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("userLogs.Name", name);

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pull("userLogs", new BsonDocument(){
            { "Name", name }
            });

collection.UpdateOne(query, update);
```